# fallout 4 nuka world shooting raiders

Tags: fallout-4

I've been playing nuka world, and I know that raiders are gang locked and that killing one pack raider wont set of operatior or disciple raiders hostile.
My question is; If i shoot raiders outside the gates, that is, in the wasteland where they frequently patrol collecting slaves and fighting, will i turn that specific gang hostile upon return.

Comment: You can always try it, see what happens, and reload to a previous save if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm (through testing) that you will only turn nearby Raiders hostile towards you. If you kill, say, two of them that are close by and return to the city/park, they will not be hostile towards you. An interesting little tidbit is that killing a raider of one faction will not necessarily cause a nearby raider of a separate faction hostile